# MySQL rows to columns with dynamic names

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to convert a singular column into several ones for two values.
Unfortunately all the examples that I found don't fit my case.

I would like to keep the first three columns and then have for each Year_Month the sales and the revenue.
But the Year_Month are not static because it's a query on the last 12 months only, this is why I cannot use existing examples because the name of the columns will not be static.
For the moment my table looks like this:

| ID1 | ID2 | isTest | Year_Month | Sales | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | 0 | 2020-10 | 50 | 1000.32 |
| 456 | DEF | 0 | 2021-04 | 100 | 2000.57 |

The output that I would need is this:

| ID1 | ID2 | isTest | 2021-04 Sales | 2020-10 Sales | 2021-04 Revenue | 2020-10 Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC | 0 | 0 | 50 | 0 | 1000.32 |
| 456 | DEF | 0 | 100 | 0 | 2000.57 | 0 |

How can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is PIVOT. Not supported in MySQL. Emulate. But the best way - transform on the client side.

Comment: Yep. Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).